# JustMock capture return value of CallOriginal

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, justmock

I was wondering if there was a way/workaround to be able to capture the output from an Arrange call in JustMock.

e.g. this is the kind of thing that I would like to do:

```
Mock.Arrange(() => foo.Bar()).CallOriginal(result => { /* stuff I want to do with the result */ });
```

I have actually done something similar already to capture parameters, but as I said, I haven't been able to figure out how to capture the return value. Here is how to capture the parameters though:

```
string myVar;

void Setup() {
    Mock.Arrange(() => foo.Bar(Arg.Matches<string>(val => Capture(val))).CallOriginal();
}

private boolean Capture(string val) {
    myVar = val;
    // any other stuff
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: found a (ridiculous) solution. Leaving this question in case someone else needs it, or if anyone else finds a better way.

```
bool callOriginal = false;
string myVar;
string myRes;

void Setup() {
    Mock.Arrange(() => foo.Bar(Arg.Matches<string>(val => Capture(val))).Returns(() => CallOriginalMethod());
    Mock.Arrange(() => foo.Bar(Arg.Matches<string> val => CallOriginal()
}

private boolean Capture(string val) {
    if (callOriginal) return false;
    myVar = val;
    // any other stuff
    return true;
}
private boolean CallOriginal() {
    return callOriginal;
}
private string CallOriginalMethod() {
    callOriginal = true;
    var res = foo.Bar(myVar); //here we get the return value
    myRes = res;
    callOriginal = false;
    return res;
}
```

This will not work for multithreaded applications, but it works for what I need.